# Publishing Android app on play store

Tags: android, publishing

I haven't published any android app before. So I just want to ask can I publish my app worldwide with same play store account or **do I need the different account for each country?**.

Comment: nope, you can publish your app with the same account  ,just select all countries

Comment: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/113469?hl=de&ref_topic=7072031 Just follow Googles help site

Comment: yes you can publish your app on worldwide with your same play store account.

Comment: @ShaifaliRajput thank you so much

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it concerns Google Play Store policies and procedures, rather than programming. Please refer to: [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?‍](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165), [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746)

Answer (score 0):

You dont need multiple account for multiple countries. you can restrict your app for countries or you can publish it worldwide.

[image]